# Storing complete Json vs Json in columns

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am developing a classified app for android where i have to fetch data from web server and show in app in form of ListView. For this, I was first fetching the whole JSON, and converting into table for and saving into SQLite in form of rows and column. then showing it in ListView, thinking that it will help loading faster and be useful as cache.

But then I have my hand on one popular classified app.. and saw its sqlite database. It is storing the whole JSON as it if into one single cell.

Now I wonder what is the correct approach. Am I doing extra processing to do all this stuff? Is following my approach going to benefit me in long run?  Guide me please.

Thank you.

Comment: Each approach has its pluses and minuses; one is not necessarily more correct than the other. Do you need to search on the contents of the JSON often? If so, your approach may be better, or there may very well be other bottlenecks. Follow the rule of thumb of avoiding [premature optmisation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: Yes I have to search whenever user applies some filter. But then I see every other app reloads data from internet after applying filter